# How to implement Google Play In-App Update and use Play Core Library with Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin.android, google-play

Google provides a new way to implement in-app update : https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/in-app-updates that can be used to force users to update their app with the latest version available.

To be able to use this new feature, it requires the use of Play Core Library 1.5.0 or higher : https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/playcore

It is possible to use it from Xamarin and to implement in-app update with this new capability ?

Regards

Comment: I am literally working on this right now will get back to you as soon as I am done

Comment: I guess this is unavailable for now, I am planning to make a Xamarin Binding for Play Core will get back to you guys as soon as it's done

Comment: It would be great! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** CHECK https://github.com/PatGet/XamarinPlayCoreUpdater

I was able to come up with the Xamarin binding for the play core library which can be found on my drive here

Will be packaging it to NuGet soon, will update here once I do

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! No offense, but would it be possible to get the sources instead of a binary? Downloading and using an unknown binary file is a security risk...

Comment: Lol, sure I will be updating the package over Nuget soon, will post the link once I do!

Comment: @FreakyAli Have you updated the Package to Nuget yet? did not found one such yet ?

Comment: Check out this Nuget package https://github.com/PatGet/XamarinPlayCoreUpdater

Comment: Thank you for this library! Even in 2022 I haven't found any other libraries for in-app updating for Xamarin.Forms Android. I will try implement this in my app this weekend.

Comment: Is there a blog post or working code we can use to implement the in-app updates in Xamarin.Forms?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for new developers of Xamarin Android as i was looking for solution and couldn't find anywhere so implemented it for C# based on java implementation suggested on android forums. Here is my example - install the Google play core library Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Base from nuget manager. And add the namespaces to the MainActivity.cs or Any activity where you want to check for updates :

```
   using Com.Google.Android.Play.Core.Appupdate;
   using Com.Google.Android.Play.Core.Tasks;
   using Com.Google.Android.Play.Core.Install.Model;
```

Create a variable for  IAppUpdateManager in your activity and Implement the IOnSuccessListener on that activity which has the method OnSuccess as under:

```
public void OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object p0)
        {
            if ((p0 as AppUpdateInfo).UpdateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UpdateAvailable && (p0 as AppUpdateInfo).IsUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.Immediate))
            {
                appUpdateManager.StartUpdateFlowForResult(p0 as AppUpdateInfo, this, AppUpdateOptions.NewBuilder(AppUpdateType.Immediate).Build(), TaskId);
            }
        }
```

You can change the AppUpdateType to FLEXIBLE instead of Immediate if that's your requirement. And check for update as under wherever you wish to in your activity.

```
appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.Create(this);
         // Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
        var appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.AppUpdateInfo;
        if (appUpdateInfoTask != null)
        {
            //Register the listener and you can check for the response of this listener at OnSuccess method implemented.
            appUpdateInfoTask.AddOnSuccessListener(this);
        }
```

There are more options available in the library that you can check here and implement as needed. Remember it is Java or Kotlin but above example will help for C# implementation : https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/kotlin-java#java

Answer (score 0):

For MAUI, everything is now implemented in one line:

- Add NuGet package to your project:

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Oscore.Maui.Android.InAppUpdates" Version="1.0.0" />
```

- Add the following to your `MauiProgram.cs` `CreateMauiApp` method:

```cs
builder
    .UseMauiApp<App>()
    .UseAndroidInAppUpdates()
    .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
    {
        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
    });
```

Sources: https://github.com/oscoreio/Maui.Android.InAppUpdates